# Would like to append to my build.gradle before building a particular flavor. Is this possible?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using `Dynatrace` and wish to only have it applied for prod builds so I wish to separate it out into a separate file before appending to `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.dynatrace.tools.android'

dynatrace {
    defaultConfig {
        startupPath 'https://mypath/end'
        applicationId 'MyApp'
        agentProperties 'DTXSendEmptyAutoAction': 'true', 'DTXLogLevel': 'debug', 'DTXAllowAnyCert': 'true', 'DTXVersionAPKit': '6.5', 'DTXAutoActionTimeoutMilliseconds': '5000', 'DTXInstrumentLifecycleMonitoring': 'true'
    }
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            startupPath 'https://mypath'
        }
    }
}

compile dynatrace.agent()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile it with particular productFlavor which of name is `global`, please try this.

```
globalCompile dynatrace.agent()
```